# ln -s symbolic link command error

Tags: terminal

I tried to use the `ln -s` command to create a symbolic link to offload storage onto a separate volume and get the following error:

```
ln -s/Volumes/NONAME/POP-emailaccount@provider.net/ ~/Library/Mail/V2/POP-emailacount@provider.net
ln: illegal option -- /
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file
```

Can't interpret what was illegal about what I did. Can anyone walk me through it.

Comment: thanks, i had the space in there but orginally my disc/volume name was "NO NAME" and so that threw a no such volume error because of the extra space in the syntax. when i changed the name of the disc and took that space out and retyped the command line I missed putting the space in after the -s command.  thanks so much for sharp eyes and to next answerer who also saw the error.  works like a charm now and my emails are stored on external drive. why that should require a metahporical act of congress is beyond me, but that's apple for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate the arguments on the command line. Try

```
ln -s /Volumes/NONAME/POP-emailaccount@provider.net/ ~/Library/Mail/V2/POP-emailacount@provider.net
```

(note the space character after `-s`)